# Animate Google Chart Transition Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm attempting to animate my google line chart multiple times, but my chart refuses to transition more than once. In the example below it will display the first data set and transition right to the fourth, skipping the two in the middle. How can I fix this behavior?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var options;
      var chart;
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(prep);
      function prep(){
        chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        options = {
            colors: ['Red','Purple','Blue'],
            animation:{duration: 1000,easing: 'linear'}
        };
        drawChart();
      }
      function triggerChart(data){
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
      function drawChart(){

        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Hour', 'First', 'Second', 'Third'],
          [1,1,2,3],
          [2,2,3,4]
        ]);
        triggerChart(data);

        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Hour', 'First', 'Second', 'Third'],
          [3,2,3,4],
          [4,5,6,7]
        ]);
        setTimeout(function(){triggerChart(data);},2000);

        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Hour', 'First', 'Second', 'Third'],
          [5,5,6,7],
          [6,7,8,9]
        ]);
        setTimeout(function(){triggerChart(data);},4000);

        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Hour', 'First', 'Second', 'Third'],
          [7,11,12,13],
          [8,12,13,14]
        ]);
        setTimeout(function(){triggerChart(data);},6000);
      }
    </script>
    <div id="chart" style="width:900px;height:600px"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `triggerChart()` is called always with same set of data and it is the last one.

You have to move assignment of `data` to `setTimeout` call.

**Update:** Reason for this behavior: `data` is global variable and sequence of execution is:

- first `data` assignment
- call of `triggerChart(data)`
- second `data` assignment
- third `data` assignment
- fourth `data` assignment
- call of `triggerChart(data)`
- call of `triggerChart(data)`
- call of `triggerChart(data)`

Another solution is to left `data` out of `setTimeout()` but in that case you have to use 4 different variable names for data. For example `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4`.

Comment: I see now, everything to do with setTimeout has to be within it's function. Thank you!